# How to mount Mac Mavericks 10.9.1 to Windows Vista Home Premium shared folder via SMB

Tags: macos, networking, mac, windows-vista, smb

I've been trying for days to connect my Mac running Mavericks 10.9.1 to my old PC running Vista Home Premium on my home network. I'd like to use it simply as file sharing server. I use my mac to connect to Windows server on a daily basis so I'm familiar with the process yet I can get my junker home PC to let my mac connect to it. Here is what I have:

1.Mac and Windows PC are in same workgroup and are visible to eachother (I only care about the mac controlling files on PC).

2.PC file share is turned on in Network Center

3.Shared folder in question, granting access to my user name.

4.I open finder "Connect to server" as seen here

[image]

5.I know it finds the pc because I'm prompted to log in almost immediately (if i put in a nonexistant the connection takes for ever then fails)

[image]

6.When i try to log in as a guest or put my windows credentials in I the message below were as I normally I get promoted for what volumes I want to mount.
[image]

7.I've tried different combinations for `smb://` and `cifs://` but to no avail. What could I be missing? I've also tried turning off windows firewall and enabling SMB according to this post -->http://csg.trinhall.cam.ac.uk/tips/smb/winvista , and tried changing `lmcompatibilitylevel` from 3 to 1 in Vista's registry. Nothing!

Comment: are you sure the guest account is turned on on the vista computer, and the share folder has allowed guest to access that information?

Comment: Guest User was turned off, I turned it on but still nothing. I've also tried logging in as my user "kev" which is the administer and password protected, I don't have any other users.

Comment: after you turn on guest account, restart both computers, figure out what the pc account name is and type //accountname in any file explorer address.

Comment: I did, no luck. http://csg.trinhall.cam.ac.uk/tips/smb/winvista does that tutorial need to be done?

Comment: does vista have something like [this](http://puu.sh/70ywT.png)? i can't remember to be honest

Comment: Yes, it does. I have network discover turned on and files sharing on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13102/discussion-between-sickest-and-kev)

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching and many failed attempts I finally got my MacBook Pro to network with my Vista machine. I noticed that the Vista machine was behind on Service Pack updates. After installing SP1 and SP2 along with about 160 security patches voila, networking madness!!

**Bottom line: *made sure your machine is up to date!***